# Change permalink for a single post type only

Tags: permalinks

At present I'm using this permalink structure `/%category%/%postname%/`. There are some existing post type. I want to change permalink for image post type to `image/%post_id%/`, and don't want to affect other post type and their permalinks.

Answer (score 1):

This will be done when you [register_post_type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) :

```
  $args = array(
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'book' ),
      ); 

    register_post_type( 'book', $args );
```

IMPORTANT ! Remember to go to wp-admin options > permalink and click SAVE on that page for the changes to take effect.

Comment: I'm using core post type "Image" (theme default). So how can i re-declare it? Please elaborate. I added above code in functions.php and changed 'book' to 'image' & it didn't work.

Comment: Great! hope it helped. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

I would give the [Custom Post Type Permalinks](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/) plugin a try (it sounds like it will allow you to do exactly what you want).

Alternatively you could probably manually edit your rewrite rules (in .htaccess), however re-saving your permalink settings would probably reset your rules each time.

Hope that helps, have fun!

Comment: but that change only for custom post type, not for default one. How it will work for default post types?

Comment: It's better etiquette to reply here with your solution in case someone else runs into the same problem.

Comment: i didn't solve this. I just created a new post type named "Image" and called all arguments by using 'support' in argument array. Still there are some problems with it :( that it is calling wp default argument, while as i need theme functions in custom post type. Still finding this answer. Do u know abt it?